# Distribution upgrade stuck on postgresql confirmation window

Tags: upgrade, package-management, postgresql

I am upgrading ubuntu to new version, and the graphical distribution update now got stuck on this "pseudo-window" for postgresql.

What should I do? I cannot cancel the upgrade in any way cleanly; there is no "cancel". But I am now stuck.

The terminal window is not clickable. I cannot enter the terminal.

[image: Upgrade screenshot]

Comment: Hit the Tab key till it highlights OK, then press Enter.

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you come up to windows like that during installations, they are not clickable.  Instead, press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> until you see the OK highlighted, then press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know windows like that from apt get installations. I just didn't know the tabs/enters will work in the "small" terminal :))

Comment: So now I am facepalming myself. But it worked!

Comment: @KarelBílek It's OK, we all have moments like that.  Even I get them at my job and I work around thousands of servers every day.  =)